# How to modify BoundField's DataFormatString in code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, string-formatting

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="articleList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="FullName, Name">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Length" HeaderText="Size" DataFormatString="{0:#,### B}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Because Byte seems confusing and crowded, I have tried to reach the `DataFormatString="{0:#,### B}"` of the BoundField with code to divide to 1024, but could not succeed.

I have the following code which I do not know what to write it on the left side of `=`. I need a code like

```
 articleList.BoundFields[1].DataFormatString = String.Format("{0:#,### KB}", Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Length")) / Convert.ToDecimal(1024), 2));
```

How can I change file size value from Bytes to KiloBytes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the `GridView` to manipulate the underlying data something like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="articleList" RowDataBound="OnGridViewRowDataBound">
    ...
</asp:GridView>


protected void OnGridViewRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = e.DataItem as YourClass;
    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = ConvertToKiloBytes(dataItem);
}
```